# Recursion - Triangle put the call before the loop

Tags: java, recursion

The function works correctly but prints have an inverted triangle.

The founction:

```
public static int Triangle(int n) {
    Random r = new Random();

    if (n == 1)
        return r.nextInt(4) + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(r.nextInt(4) + 1);
    }

    System.out.println();
    return Triangle(n - 1);
}
}
```

The output:

```
2224
112
11
4
```

I tried to put the recursive calls before the for loop so that the output will be:

```
1
11
234
4345
```

But I get a compile error (for loop with a red line under it).

Error After Running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unreachable code

at test1.Triangle(test1.java:16)
at test1.main(test1.java:6)
```

Comment: unreachable code means, you have written code at a point, where it can´t get executed anymore. For example behind a `return`, where it is impossible to get executed.

Comment: Please show you code with the unresolved compilation problem.

Comment: Hint: if you get a compile error ... stop. Don't run. There is absolutely no point in running something if you already know that it is broken. Instead: focus on the compiler error message. Turn to the line it points out; and then keep reading the message. Because: typically those error messages are **really** good. They tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Bonus hint: don't leave out the braces; even for one line statements, like `if (foo) bar()` ... always go for : `if (foo) { bar() }`

Answer (score 1):

In a recursive function, the breaking condition check must precede the recursive call, or else the breaking return will never be reached. Which sounds pretty much like what your code seems to have done (You didn't post your modified code, so this is guessing).

If you want to invert your output, try passing the original size as an additional parameter and using the difference between it and your `n` as the length to output.

```
... Triangle(int size, int n)
...
for (int i=0; i < (size-n+1); ++i) { ...}
return Triangle(size, n-1);
```

To keep the interface consistent (i.e. to make sure `size` is never smaller than the initial `n`, try introducing a `TriangleHelper` which calls `Triangle(size, size)` at the beginning.